# beginner issue ved java and android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I just started programming android apps with eclipse..

I try to follow this guide: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html
but I can't get further than here..

When I run my app through my htc phone, it just shows an empty app....

Then I tried creating a totally new android application in eclipse, and as a standard, there is an app with a text writing "Hello world"..

And when I show my activity_main.xml in graphical layout, it shows an app with this text "hello world".... but still, when I run it through my htc, I still just get an empty app...

How can this be, what am I missing?

Thanks.

Edit: actually, the app on the phone is not totally empty... it does show the standard head-banner with the android logo and the name of my app. But no textview...

Comment: please add the `MainActivity.java`s `onCreate()` method and your `activity_main.xml` file here.

Comment: I believe your text view is hidden behind the title bar. Try adjusting the layout or calling `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` in `onCreate()` method of `MainActivity.java` that will totally hide the title.

Comment: Also, make sure you're calling something like `setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);` in your activity/fragment.

Answer (score 0):

First close the version of application that is already running on the HTC device. OR best thing woulld be uninstall it and try again.
It should work

Also, set the content view

```
setContView(R.layout.your XML file name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your activity does not add any content to the window so therefore nothing is shown.

Seems like you already have the wizard-generated layouts in `res/layout`. Just add

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

to `onCreate()` where `activity_main` corresponds to `res/layout/activity_main.xml` and that layout file actually contains the UI you want displayed.

Also import your generated resource identifiers:

```
import com.example.nytapp.R;
```

You will also need to call the superclass `onCreate()` in your `onCreate()`. Add

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

as the first line in your `onCreate()`.

The warning

> ActivityManager: Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front

is nothing to worry about - if you didn't change your code and try to run it, the app won't get reinstalled and launched but just an existing instance is brought to front.

Comment: Still the same.... exactly the same... titlebar still showing, and no text.... :(